# How to delete all user names in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I am testing the user access control functionalities of DolphinDB database. As I quite often need to start all over again, I need to find a convenient way to delete all user names as an administrator. I have tried the following:

```
each(deleteUser, getUserList())
```

The idea is to use the template function "each" to apply "deleteUser" to each of the user names returned from function getUserList(). It returns the following error message:

```
Not allowed to create void vector
```

I don't quite understand why the script fails. Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Use "loop" instead of "each". The template function "loop" in DolphinDB does not have any requirement for the result.